# After I modified my Python code in Pycharm, how to deploy the change to my Portainer?

Tags: linux, python-3.x, portainer

Perhaps it is a basic question but I am really not a profession in Portainer.
I have a local Portainer, a Pycharm to manage the Python code. What should I do after I modified my code and deploy this change to the local Portainer?

Thx

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, if you feel like an answer solved or helped you to resolve the issue please consider clicking the check mark next to it in order to 'accept' the answer. This might help other people in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have mounted the folder where your code resides directly in the container the changes will be also be applied in your container so no further action is required.

If you have not mounted the folder to your container (for example if you copy the code when you build the image), you would have to rebuild the image. Of course this is a lot more work so I would recommend using the mounted volumes.

Comment: Thanks, 
I just tried `docker stack rm 'image'`and `make install-local` it works.